# Regex Checking Multiple URL's?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to check if the URL equals to any of the below URLS but I can't get it to work.

The Regex check will be implemented in Google Event Manager to check social clicks for Twitter, Facebook, YouTube, RSS and Google+

I tried Click URL matches RegEx:

`twitter.com/example|facebook.com/example|youtube.com/c/example|example.com/feed/rss/|google.com/b/107779391932152668583/+example/`

Comment: You need to escape all of the periods `.` to be `\.`, and possibly all the `/` to be `\/` ...

Comment: Is this about Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Thanks  l'L'l, that did the trick! :)

Comment: Just one more thing... Any idea how I can write the **+** in:
`google\.com\/b\/107779391932152668583\/+Example\/`

Comment: I doubt you need to escape forward slashes. A plus should be escaped as well as a dot: `google\.com/b/107779391932152668583/\+Example/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only special characters you need to escape in your pattern are

- a dot
- a plus symbol

GA regexps do not use regdx delimiters, thus you do not have to escape forward slashes (you need them to test at online regex testers).

Use

```
twitter\.com/example|facebook\.com/example|youtube\.com/c/example|example\.com/feed/rss/|google\.com/b/107779391932152668583/\+example/
```

Comment: Everything works perfectly besides the Google+ account.
Any ideas? I think it's got something to do with the +?

`google\.com/b/107779391932152668583/\+username/`

Comment: Try putting the plus into brackets. `[+]`.

Comment: Still can't get the Google+ URL to work.
Very strange.... I thought [+] would do the trick...

Comment: Are you sure therev is a literal plus, not rendered HTML entity? Try replacing `\+` with `%43` or `&#43;` or something like that.